# MdCommonModule in custom angular 4 module with Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I write custom library on Angular 4 + Material and i have a lot of problems.
One of custom component is SearchComponent. Nothing difficult.

**search.component.ts**

```
@Component({
selector: 'cis-search',
templateUrl: './search.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
host: {
    'class': 'search'
}})
export class CisSearchComponent implements OnChanges {}
```

module

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdListModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule
],
providers: [SearchService],
declarations: [CisSearchComponent],
exports: [CisSearchComponent]
})
export class CisSearchModule {}
```

and package this module rollup.
In main project I write

```
{
    provide: DOCUMENT, useValue: {value: document}
}
```

Error

```
TypeError: this._document.createElement is not a function
at MdCommonModule._checkTheme (material.es5.js:191)
at new MdCommonModul
```

How does fix it?
All dependencies installed @latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is

```
constructor(@Optional() @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any) {}
```

into your custom module.
Angular 4.0.0